# High latency during adding items to azure table

Tags: c#, azure, task, task-parallel-library, azure-table-storage

Using the following code I'm trying to insert entities into an azure table.

```
    public void AddItems<T>(T[] entitis, string tableName) where T : TableServiceEntity
    {
        using (new TimeLogger(_logger, "save items in table " + tableName + ", count: " + entitis.Length + ", duration: {0}"))
        {
            tableName = GetSafeTableName(tableName);
            var items = RemoveDuplicates(entitis).ToArray();

            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            var context = _tableStorage.GetDataServiceContext();

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                context.AttachTo(tableName, items[i]);
                context.UpdateObject(items[i]);

                if (i % 10 == 0 || i == items.Length - 1)
                {
                    var context1 = context;

                    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<DataServiceResponse>(
                        context1.BeginSaveChangesWithRetries,
                        context1.EndSaveChangesWithRetries,
                        context1);

                    tasks.Add(task);

                    context = _tableStorage.GetDataServiceContext();
                }
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

The caller of this method passing items in multiple paritions. In my tests I have found out that for 450 items in different partition there is about 7s to 8s latency. I think that I'm doing something wrong here. Any comment is very appreciated.

Comment: What's your `DefaultConnectionLimit`? (How many of these 450 web requests can we expect to be executed in parallel?) Is this code running in the same data center as the storage account?

Comment: Thanks, the DefaultConnectionLimit is set to 48. Also, in my tests I found out that batches of 10 items in multiple partitions is providing the best latency. And finally, the code is running in the same data centre.

Comment: I should mention that there could be some transient problem on my network. this morning the same code is running under 3 seconds!

Comment: Now I see 2.5 to 3 seconds latency for 450 items in multiple paritions. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There must be something going on. I've run tests that inserted 2000 entities in under 5 seconds with no problems at all.

As @smarx already mentioned, there are some networking parameters you can set that influence performance. There is/was a [blog post with all of them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx). It seems to be down at this moment, but hopefully it will come back. The following configuration snippet embodies some of the suggestions from that article, and may help you:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="45"/>
    </connectionManagement>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager useNagleAlgorithm="true" expect100Continue="false" />
  </settings>
</system.net>
```

Since you're using Tasks, you might also check if you're exhausting your ThreadPool. Use Perfmon to check how many threads are active while your test is running. If the count keeps climbing, or goes to a very large number, then that may be your problem. In that case you might try skipping the use of Tasks, and just track the async results of the Begin/End calls yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So far I've come to understand that the problem could be related to threading issues.

Comment: Also, in your tests did you add items in a single partition or multiple partitions? Thanks.

Comment: I was adding them all to a single partition, but not using batching. So it was 2000 separate requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just ran a test for a single partition and for 2000 items it took 9332ms. I'm runnning the code from my machine and I assume that it would be faster if i deploy it to the cloud. Also, I ran perfmon on the process and at most 16 threads have allocated to these requests. I think I might be making a mistake. Is it possible for you to share code here? Thanks.

Comment: I found what I was using, and now that I think about it that was mostly doing queries, not writes. Sorry about that. 

I still think it might be worth trying with the Task library involved. If you still want to gather more info is set up a separate storage account and enable storage metrics on it. Then run your test, and see what the metrics say. That'll give you a good idea of the server latency, so you'll know if you can do much more on the client side.